# What numerical representation do scalars, matrices, vectors and arrays have?

Tags: matlab, precision

In MATLAB,What are the data types/classes, of each of these variable types: scalar, matrix, vector and array?
Are they all represented as `double` precision values?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, variables can be classified with respect to data type and geometry, two independent concepts. Data types, or classes, include *double* (64-bit floating-point number), *single* (32-bit floating-point number), *uint8* (unsigned 8-bit integer), among many others; for a non-exhaustive list of available types, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html).

A separate concept is the geometry or size of a variable:

- The most general term is *array*, which means a collection of arbitrarily many elements of a given data type arranged in a hyperrectangular structure with arbitrarily many dimensions. (This is similar to tensors, but without any particular mathematical properties.)
- Then you have *matrices*, which are 2-dimensional arrays; usually, this name is reserved for those arrays whose third and higher dimensions are degenerate, or *singleton*. (If the nonsingleton dimensions are, for example, the second and the third, this is usually just called an array.)
- *Vectors* are a special case of matrices, when only its first dimension (*column vector*) or second dimension (*row vector*) is nonsingleton.
- Finally, you have scalars, which are commonly referred to just by their data type (e.g. *a double*, *an int8*), in contrast to higher-dimensional variables (*a single row vector*, *a logical array*).

Of course the nomenclature has some flexibility, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you initialiase them, of course. The default is `double`, but you can easily initialise them as `uint8`, `hex`, `logical`, `single` or whatever precision/numerical representation you require.

```matlab
zeros(3,2) % 3-by-2 double matrix
ones(1,1,'logical') % boolean scalar
zeros(3,3,'unit8')  % unit8 3-by-3 matrix
... % etc
```

Note that all your mentioned types are actually matrices: a scalar is a 1-by-1 matrix, a matrix is a matrix, a vector is non-existant (but I presume you mean a column array) and an array is an 1-by-N matrix, usually used for cell-arrays or char-arrays.